# 500KB json file parsed in Android environment

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, android-json

I need to find a faster solution to parse a json file with 500KB. the structure is something like

```
{
    "response": {
        "code": 0,
        "msg": "OK",
        "searchparameter": {
            "bikes": { … },
            "cars": { 
                 "a":{
                     values[{...}]
                  },
                 "b":{},
                 "c":{},
                 "d":{},
                  "e":{},
           ...

            }
        }
   }
}
```

I tried `gson.fromJson(jsontxt, Response.class)`, but it causes me like more than 5 mins to parse..  Is there any solutions that is suitable for me? How can I do `JSONReader` by `gson` in this case? and would it be helpful? any helps would be appreciated. thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do you need to deserialize the entire file? If not, and are looking for something very specific, you could try to read it as a normal file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing huge JSON object in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553101/parsing-huge-json-object-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a streaming API:

- For Gson, https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming
- Or switch to Jackson: [Parsing huge JSON object in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553101/parsing-huge-json-object-in-android/5553647#5553647)

Comment: i have gson and jackson with streaming maybe faster, but meaning i need parse it in token level.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Gson` itself but to make it useful try it in using `Asyntask` so you can tell the user to wait by showing `progressDialog`